# TeamCity linking issue with mspdb80.dll using PlatformBuilder 6.0

Tags: teamcity, platform-builder

I kind of have a good idea of whats going on, just no idea how to fix it. We are using TeamCity 6.5 to build a platform builder 6.0 project via command line script. The problem we are running into is with multiple visual studios installed.

Team City doesn't seem to be aware of which Visual Studio to use in its path.

```
LINK : fatal error LNK1101: incorrect MSPDB80.DLL version; recheck installation of this product
```

What I think is happening is its starting the mspdbsrv.exe for visual studio 2010 instead of 2005 and failing during the sysgen. The strange part is this problem only exists running from team city, if we manually invoke our .bat file from a command prompt it works fine. So our SetEnv.bat that gets generated and run might be setting up an environment but again, TeamCity doesn't get the new environment variables or something.

Any help would be great!
Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We faced the very same problem, and solved it.

This is happening also if there is no other Visual Studio installed than 2005.
The root cause is that some mspdb*.* files are not correctly updated, when Studio Service Packs or Updates are installed.

Solution:

- Make sure that you have installed and running TeamCity as a user, and not from SYSTEM account.
- Make sure you have installed VS80 hotfix KB920770. This may not be necessary, but who knows.
- Reboot your build machine, make sure that no build is started by TeamCity, as sometimes the executables are locked if a build is started.
- Search for mspdb*.* files - in every and each folder of your machine.
- You should find mspdb80.dll, mspdbcore.dll, mspdbsrv.exe on your machine as several incompatible versions.
- The files residing in "c:\WINCE600\SDK\BIN\I386\" will be the problematic ones (these are too old, not updated correctly).
- The files in "c:\Program Files\Microsoft Visual Studio 8\Common7\IDE" should be the newer ones.
- Rename the three older files in WINCE600 to some name (e.g. xxx_mspdb80.dll)
- Copy the newer files from Common7\IDE folder to c:\WINCE600\SDK\BIN\I386
- Restart your machine.
- Try a new build with TeamCity. This helped us.